# Loading meshes in assimp to a vbo in opengl

Tags: opengl, vbo, assimp

I'm using the code at the bottom of this tutorial to load meshes using assimp.
[Mesh Loading](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/mesh.html)

So I load the meshes and then load the first one into a vbo and then link them to a vao.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vertexArray1); //Bind to first VAO
glBindVertexArray(_vertexArray1);
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBufferCube1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferCube1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_point_count * 3 * sizeof (float), &g_vp[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc1);
glVertexAttribPointer(loc1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc2);
glVertexAttribPointer(loc2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

But how can I load the second mesh into the vbo?
As in should the second mesh be contained at `g_vp[g_point_count * 3 * sizeof (float)]`?
Because I have tried that and it doesn't work but it's possible something else is wrong.

Comment: Typically, you would generate another VBO for the next mesh. If you really want to put it into the first VBO, you would need to make that VBO big enough for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vao based drawing, you can store different vbos in different vaos. When you are drawing the scene, using glBindVertexArray(vao) and glBindVertexArray(0) to swith between different vaos. There are also better solutions. You can store multiple objects in one vao, but record the index data of each object. Then you can draw each object using [glDrawElementsBaseVertex](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xml) by specifying the index.

This tutorial shows an example of doing the render with glDrawElementsBaseVertex + assimp
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html

Comment: Yes my problem is that I load my meshes like this...

 `for (unsigned int m_i = 0; m_i < scene->mNumMeshes; m_i++) {
    const aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[m_i];
    g_point_count = mesh->mNumVertices;
    for (unsigned int v_i = 0; v_i < mesh->mNumVertices; v_i++) {
      if (mesh->HasPositions ()) {
        const aiVector3D* vp = &(mesh->mVertices[v_i]);
        printf ("      vp %i (%f,%f,%f)\n", v_i, vp->x, vp->y, vp->z);
        g_vp.push_back (vp->x); `

Which is code I copied from a tutorial and I'm wondering how exactly I can access the second mesh loaded into g_vp ?

Comment: scene->mNumMeshes tells you how many meshes are there in the file. For each mesh, you can record the index. for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < meshes.size() ; i++) {
        meshes[i].MaterialIndex = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mMaterialIndex;        
        meshes[i].NumIndices = pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces * 3;
        meshes[i].BaseVertex = numVertices;
        meshes[i].BaseIndex = numIndices;
        
        numVertices += pScene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices;
        numIndices  += meshes[i].NumIndices;
    }